# Executing JavaScript func for a series of HTML Textfields

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html

### Summary

- I am making a ordering form that will multiply "Qty of Items" by "Unit price" to give the "Subtotal" by JavaScript.
- The orders are stored in MySQL db and retrieved via PHP.
- I want to manually enter "Unit Price," I wish after I type that number in the multiplication will happen.
- There are 10 rows of items (an array).
- All written code performs correctly as expected.

### Problem

- My JavaScript function only runs for the first row, not any others.
- I want to run for every row, for each item type.

### My Code

#### JS

```
function calc(){
    baseprice=parseInt(document.getElementById("baseprice").value);
    units=parseInt(document.getElementById("units").value);
    x=baseprice*units;
    document.getElementById("sub").value=x;
}
```

#### PHP / SQL

```
$alter=0;
//previous miscellaneous code
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    $alter=$alter+1;
 //edit       
$subCalc="<td><input name='units_".$alter."' id='units_".$alter."' type='hidden' value=".$rows['SUM(pizza_orders.qty)']."><input name='baseprice_".$alter."' id='baseprice_".$alter."' type='text' size='2' onchange='calc(this);'></td><td><input name='sub_".$alter."' id='sub_".$alter."' type='text' size='3'></td></tr>";

 //alternates the table row colour by modulus
    if ($alter %2 ==0){
        echo "<tr><td>".$rows['item_order']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$rows['SUM(pizza_orders.qty)']."</td>".$subCalc;
    }else{
            echo "<tr class=\"alt\"><td>".$rows['item_order']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$rows['SUM(pizza_orders.qty)']."</td>".$subCalc;
    }
}
```

#### Sample Result / Situation

[image]

#### Extension

Making a grand total at the bottom right, adding all of the sub-totals fields as they are "onchange".

```
subTotal=parseInt(document.getElementById("sub" + el.id.replace('baseprice', '')).value);                                                                                   document.getElementById("grandtotal")=  subTotal+parseInt(document.getElementById("grandtotal").value);
```

[Demo > JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/leechyeah/eVLGU/4/)

Comment: Looks like you need to loop over all of you rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An id has to be unique on a page, you have multiple input's with the same id on the page. Hence why it is only every performing the calculation on the first input. Your best bet is to append a numerical value to 'baseprice' and 'units' input to distinguish each row. In addition pass the 'this' keyword into the calc function to reference the element that has triggered the function.

Example row:

```
    <tr>
    <td>
    <input id="units_1" name="units_1" type="hidden" value="10" />
<!-- attach an onchange handler to baseprice_1, when a change is made trigger the calc function. -->
    <input id="baseprice_1" name="baseprice_1" type="text" onchange="calc(this);" />
    <input id="sub_1" name="sub_1" type="text" />
    </td>
    </tr>
```

JS:

```
/* An array to store the subtotals. */
grandTotalArr = [];

    function calc(el){
/* el = this (which is a reference to baseprice_1) */
        baseprice=parseInt(el.value);
        units=parseInt(document.getElementById("units" + el.id.replace('baseprice', '')).value);
        x=baseprice*units;
        document.getElementById("sub" + el.id.replace('baseprice', '')).value=x;

/* Store the subtotal in the grandTotalArr using it's id as the key. */
grandTotalArr["sub" + el.id.replace('baseprice', '')] = x;
/* Implode all values with the + operator, and evaluate as a JS expression. Once evaluated, update the grand total. */
document.getElementById('grand_total').value = eval(grandTotalArr.join('+'));
    }
```

Comment: How shall I make each id different? I want to avoid copying the same code and changing one number. eg id1, id2...
I have tried id[], this this is only for names.

Comment: I will test now. Please note that my $alter PHP var increments the name (at the moment) and can also increment the id of the input field. This is done by concatenating. 

Also, $alter is used to alternate the table colour at the same time.

Comment: Name's / Id's now incrementing by 1, each row.
Currently in JS debugging mode, I can see JS var "baseprices" equalling to the last number I typed in any "Unit Prices" row. This is good progress, but now it hasn't done the multiplication?

Comment: Oops, forgot to put in the replacement parameter for the .replace function. See above for correction.

Comment: Thank you, you are very intelligent!

Comment: I want to make a grand total field that adds all of the right hand column, ie all the subtotals. How may I do this?

Comment: `<input name="grandtotal" id="grandtotal" type="text">`

Comment: Get the input elements using getElementsByTagName, loop through them and add the values of those input fields that have an id beginning with 'sub'. Or simplify the whole process using a JavaScript library like jQuery.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble, I am still unsure of how the code works. E.G. what is "el"? May you quickly comment your code with explanations?

Comment: 'el' references 'this' passed into the calc function.

Comment: I'm almost there in understanding this. Where does the underscore "_" in baseprice_1 go?

to my understanding, i see it get baseprice_1, then units takes out the baseprice keyword, leaving the 1. this is concatenated onto "units"

Comment: Ye, that is correct. It is done to ensure you reference the corresponding units input element. baseprice_1 is associated with units_1.

Comment: Hmm, I don't seem to have any success. Please help me with the extension, which I've updated above.

Comment: See above. Note: It is usually recommended that you steer clear of using the eval function, however for your purposes you need worry.

Comment: A very neat approach. For some reason the `grand_total` textbox isn't updating yet.
I have ensured that there are no naming errors. 
What I do suspect is that the `sub` number is **not** going into the Array, which I've found in JS debugger: 

`x = 5 grandTotalArr = []`

Comment: Can you post your solution to jsfiddle for me to have a look?

Comment: Hi, see above for link. Please note each row in the table is generated by PHP sql query.

Comment: "How shall I make each id different? I want to avoid copying the same code and changing one number..."
One Word/Attribute: "Class".
set the CSS with class, and have the ids differ, then just loop through the classes to get the values and that's pretty much it.

Comment: See: http://jsfiddle.net/eVLGU/20/. It seems using an associative array with the .join function causes issues.